# How to write data in sequence from multiple device on single node in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat module using firebase realtime and I am writing data to the node using push(). I am trying to push data in sequential order but somehow it's not working. I have two devices and both devices have the same timezone with automatic pickup by the system.

I have tried by pushing data by timestamp getting from the device but there is minor millisecond difference so it's not working. I also tried with push() method provided by firebase

```
messageDatabase = firebaseDatabase.getReference(FIREBASE_CHAT).child(firebaseId)
messageDatabase.push().setValue(chatMessageItem)
```

I expect that the messages should be in order when they are sent like any social messaging app whether it is sent from two or more devices.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  Could you edit the question to explain in more detail what you're observing that illustrates why the order isn't as expected?  Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: ARe you talking that you cannot see ordered item in Firebase console or?

Comment: Exactly. If I write data from one device it writes in the order, now if I am writing data from another device to the same node, then the order will not maintain. I know that using push() method firebase generates a unique id containing the timestamp of the device but both devices have the same timezone and same time(Automatic Time from internet or service provider). I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use [firebase transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to make multiple operation on single node.

Whenever you use transactions on a database, you sacrifice some of your scalability in order to have a stronger data consistency guarantee. Transactions on the Firebase Database are no different, except maybe that developers tend to use Firebase in more highly concurrent situations.

With any transactional system: the key to keeping the system scalable is to minimize the number of clients contending to update the same data. In the case of Firebase, you'd accomplish that by running your transaction as low as possible in your JSON tree. I.e. a counter is a example of something that could work well under a transaction.